# Moving a bot through a maze with Depth First Search

Tags: java, algorithm

This is supposed to be a depth first search. I just took the idea of what it does and made my own version of it. The bot works it's way through the maze, when it finds a dead end, it moves back to original spot, and continues in a different direction than it's already gone until it reaches E the end.

```
import java.util.Stack;
import java.lang.Comparable;
import java.util.*;

class Main {

  public static int[][] maze = { 
    {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
    {9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9},
    {9,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,5,9},
    {9,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,9},
    {9,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,9},
    {9,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,9},
    {9,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,9},
    {9,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,9},
    {9,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,9},
    {9,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,3,9},
    {9,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,9},
    {9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9}
    };

    public static Deque<Coordinate> deadEnd = new ArrayDeque<Coordinate>(10);
    public static Deque<Coordinate> deq = new ArrayDeque<Coordinate>(10);


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    printMaze();
    dfs(2,10);

  }

  public static boolean isDeadEnd(Coordinate coord){
    Iterator it = deadEnd.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      if(it.next().equals(coord)){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static Coordinate setCoord(int i, int j){
    Coordinate coord = new Coordinate();
    coord.setCoord(i,j);
    return coord;
  }

  public static boolean checkCoord(Coordinate coord){
    return iterateCoord(coord);
  }

  private static boolean iterateCoord(Coordinate coord){
    Iterator it = deq.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
      if(it.next().equals(coord)){
        return true; 
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static int dfs(int i, int j){
    if(i == 9 && j == 9){
      maze[9][10] =4;
      printMaze();
      System.out.println("You're Free!");
      return 0;
    }
    Coordinate coord = new Coordinate();

if(!checkCoord(coord) && !isDeadEnd(coord)){

    if(maze[i+1][j] == 0 || maze[i+1][j] == 3){
        coord = setCoord(i+1, j);
        deq.push(coord);
        maze[i+1][j] = 4;
        printMaze();
        return dfs(i+1,j);
    }
    else if(maze[i-1][j] == 0){
        coord = setCoord((i-1),j);
    deq.push(coord);
        maze[i-1][j] = 4;
        printMaze();
        return dfs(i-1,j);
    }
    else if(maze[i][j+1] == 0){
        coord = setCoord(i,(j+1));
        deq.push(coord);
        maze[i][j+1] = 4;
        printMaze();
        return dfs(i,j+1);
    }
    else if(maze[i][j-1] == 0){
        coord = setCoord(i,(j-1));
        deq.push(coord);
        maze[i][j-1] = 4;
        printMaze();
        return dfs(i,j-1);
    }
}

    deadEnd.push(deq.pop());
    int n = deq.peek().getX();
    int m = deq.peek().getY();
   // maze[m][n] = 0;
    return dfs(n,m);
  }

  public static void printMaze() {

    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++){
        if(maze[i][j]==1){
         System.out.print(" X ");
        }
        if(maze[i][j]==0){
          System.out.print("   ");
        }
        if(maze[i][j]==2){
          System.out.print(" e ");
        }
        if(maze[i][j]==3){
          System.out.print(" E ");
        }
        if(maze[i][j]==4){
          System.out.print(" b ");
        }
        if(maze[i][j]==5){
          System.out.print(" b ");
          maze[i][j] = 1;
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}



class Coordinate{
  Integer x = 0;
  Integer y = 0;

  public int getX(){
    return x;
  }
  public int getY(){
    return y;
  }
  public void setCoord(int i, int j){
    x = i;
    y = j;
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if(obj == null){
      return false;
    }
    if(obj instanceof Coordinate){
      Coordinate test = (Coordinate) obj;
      if(test.x == this.x && test.y == this.y){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return (this == obj);
  }
  /*
  @Override
  public int hashCode(){
    return x + y * 31;
  }
    */
}
```

Comment: I'm not the person that down voted this question, or voted to close, but the first sentence in the paragraph `So I don't know if it's actually depth first search, but was wondering if anyone could see if it is.` is probably why the question got the down vote and the vote to close. The close reason is `Needs detail or clarity.` The question isn't clear because of that first sentence.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Hm, well I am the king of bad first impressions so I'm not surprised. I suppose I should have mentioned to look at the method dfs() ? It's where are the magic happens. dfs() tracks where you've been with a stack, and keeps dead end paths in an array.

Comment: A depth-first search would backtrack to the last junction in the maze, not all the way to the beginning.  Other than that, what you did appears to be in the spirit of a depth-first search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up your code, but it appears like your code performs a depth-first search.  It's more common to use a graph to represent the different paths than a queue, but your code works, as best as I can tell.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DFSMaze {

    public static int[][] maze = { 
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 }, 
            { 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9 },
            { 9, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 9 }, 
            { 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 9 },
            { 9, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 9 }, 
            { 9, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 9 },
            { 9, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 9 }, 
            { 9, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 9 },
            { 9, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 9 }, 
            { 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 9 },
            { 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9 }, 
            { 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9 } 
            };

    public static Deque<Coordinate> deadEnd = 
            new ArrayDeque<Coordinate>(10);
    public static Deque<Coordinate> deq = 
            new ArrayDeque<Coordinate>(10);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printMaze();
        dfs(2, 10);
    }

    public static boolean isDeadEnd(Coordinate coord) {
        Iterator<Coordinate> it = deadEnd.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().equals(coord)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static Coordinate setCoord(int i, int j) {
        return new Coordinate(i, j);
    }

    public static boolean checkCoord(Coordinate coord) {
        Iterator<Coordinate> it = deq.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (it.next().equals(coord)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int dfs(int i, int j) {
        if (i == 9 && j == 9) {
            maze[9][10] = 4;
            printMaze();
            System.out.println("You're Free!");
            return 0;
        }
        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate();

        if (!checkCoord(coord) && !isDeadEnd(coord)) {

            if (maze[i + 1][j] == 0 || maze[i + 1][j] == 3) {
                coord = setCoord((i + 1), j);
                deq.push(coord);
                maze[i + 1][j] = 4;
                printMaze();
                return dfs(i + 1, j);
            } else if (maze[i - 1][j] == 0) {
                coord = setCoord((i - 1), j);
                deq.push(coord);
                maze[i - 1][j] = 4;
                printMaze();
                return dfs(i - 1, j);
            } else if (maze[i][j + 1] == 0) {
                coord = setCoord(i, (j + 1));
                deq.push(coord);
                maze[i][j + 1] = 4;
                printMaze();
                return dfs(i, j + 1);
            } else if (maze[i][j - 1] == 0) {
                coord = setCoord(i, (j - 1));
                deq.push(coord);
                maze[i][j - 1] = 4;
                printMaze();
                return dfs(i, j - 1);
            }
        }

        deadEnd.push(deq.pop());
        int n = deq.peek().getX();
        int m = deq.peek().getY();
        // maze[m][n] = 0;
        return dfs(n, m);
    }

    public static void printMaze() {
        String chars = " XeEbb";
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
                int k = maze[i][j];
                if (k < 9) {
                    System.out.print(" " + chars.charAt(k));
                    if (maze[i][j] == 5) {
                        maze[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}

class Coordinate {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Coordinate() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public Coordinate(int i, int j) {
        x = i;
        y = j;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (obj instanceof Coordinate) {
            Coordinate test = (Coordinate) obj;
            if (test.x == this.x && test.y == this.y) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return (this == obj);
    }

}
```

Comment: I love that way you print the maze, I've never seen that before, it's way more sleek. You're right when you say it's not supposed to go back to the original, but I think I made a mistake in saying that. I'm pretty sure it goes only as far back until it can find a new path. When it finds a dead end path, the coords will keep popping until it finds a path it hasn't gone yet, so that would be closer to dfs(). Thanks for looking at my  code!